# Finding the support of the CDF of $(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Assume $X$ to be standard normal random variable, and define $Y$ as$$Y=\begin{cases}X,&\text{if }⌊X⌋\text{ is even}\\-X,&\text{if }⌊X⌋\text{ is odd}\end{cases}.$$

I am trying to show that $X$ and $Y$ are mutually completely dependent. For this I want to find the support of the copula of $(X,Y)$:
$$ C(u,v)=\mathbb{P}( X \leq F^{-1}(u), Y \leq G^{-1}(v)),$$
and conclude by finding the probability mass concentrated on some locus. Here $F(x) = \Phi(x)$ is the standard normal distribution of $X$, and $G(y)$ is the distribution of $Y$.

However, I am not sure how to technically tackle the $Y$, that is, how to properly split it between cases odd/even integer values.

**My approach:**
I am adding an excerpt from another question of mine (which is linked) with my approach. If my work is correct, I worked out that $$G(y)=\frac{1}{2}[1 + F(y) - F(-y)].$$
Further,\begin{align*}
C(u,v) &= \mathbb{P}(X \leq F^{-1}(u), Y \leq G^{-1}(v))\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbb{P}(X \leq F^{-1}(u), X > -G^{-1}(v)) + \mathbb{P}(X \leq F^{-1}(u), X \leq G^{-1}(v)) \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbb{P}(X \leq \min\{F^{-1}(u), G^{-1}(v)\}) + \mathbb{P}(X \in [-G^{-1}(u), F^{-1}(v)])  \right]\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[ v - F(G^{-1}(v)) + F(\min\{F^{-1}(u), G^{-1}(v)\})  \right]. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

It seems I might be able to untangle this as a function of $(u,v)$ if I find $F(G^{-1}(v))$. However, here I'm not too sure that the usual approach of finding the inverse works.

$$ y = G(G^{-1}(y)) =\frac{1}{2}[1 + F(G^{-1}(y)) - F(-G^{-1}(y))] $$
$$ 2y -1  = F(G^{-1}(y)) - F(-G^{-1}(y)) $$
$$ F^{-1}(2y -1)  = F^{-1}\left(  F(G^{-1}(y)) -F(-G^{-1}(y)) \right) \tag{2}$$

**And it seems I am stuck here**. I am thinking that it is enough to simplify $(1)$ to some convenient form, here my idea is that finding the expression for $G^{-1}(y)$ would help, but I got stuck at $(2)$.

Maybe another approach is better?

Would it be easier to show that $\mathbb{P}(X = g(Y))= 1$, where $g$ is some function of $Y$? But I still need to find the support of $C$ for following exercises.

Would appreciate any hints or suggestions on how to proceed!

Comment: @AlexFrancisco This is true. If my work is correct, the distribution function of $Y$ should be $G(y)=\frac{1}{2}[1 + F(y) - F(-y)]$, where $F$ is standard normal distribution of $X$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Thanks, I've edited the question, that was a typo from my side.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I'm following this definition: (Lancaster 1963), X and Y are mutually completely dependent if there exists a one-to-one function $\varphi$ such, that $\mathbb{P}(Y = \varphi(X))=1$. On the other hand, in the textbook it is shown that X and Y is mutually completely dependent, if the support of their copula is singular. That is, the support then is the graph of the one-to-one function.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I think that might be useful. Still, the next exercise requires to show that the $C(x,y)$ is not a shuffle of $min(x,y)$ copula ([see here, i.e., Definition 1.3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03232.pdf), or Nelsen), for which I think the expression of $C$ would be essential. Unless it is possible to conclude this without the expression of $C$?

Comment: Why don't you simply prove that $$\Pr\{X<x,Y<y\}=\Pr\{X<x\}\cdot\Pr\{Y<y\}$$?

Comment: Also you can use a criteria for mutual complete dependence  in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00184-008-0229-9

Comment: I am not sure the subtle thing on how to show that the support is singular - or in other words the area of the support in the plane is $0$? It should be quite straight-forward to show that the function is one-to-one? And one more subtle thing is about the definition of the floor function - the typical definition should be $\lfloor x \rfloor = -1$ if $-1 \leq x < 0$ but I guess you may want it to be $0$ instead?

Comment: @BGM thanks, this is a good point on the floor function. But here I think I'm following the correct definition, aren't I? I am talking about the $\mathbb{P}(\lfloor X \rfloor \text{is odd/even})  = 1/2$ part, unless you meant something else?

Comment: Have you tried to sketch the function $y = g(x)$? I guess you want something like this: https://ibb.co/g3WGmV such that it is bijective. And everything should follow?