# Finding $G^{-1}(y)$ CDF knowing that $G(y)=\frac{1}{2}[1 + F(y) - F(-y)]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are random variables,  F and G are their cdf's. If my work is correct,

$$G(y)=\frac{1}{2}[1 + F(y) - F(-y)]$$

is the CDF of

$$ Y = \left\{ \begin{array}{} X, & \text{if}~  \lfloor X \rfloor ~\text{is even} \\  -X, & \text{if}~  \lfloor X \rfloor ~\text{is odd} \end{array} \right.$$

In relation to [another question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946105/support-of-x-y-cdf-where-y-in-x-x-when-lfloor-x-rfloor-is-odd), I want to estimate 
$$ \begin{array}{} C(u,v) &= \mathbb{P}(X \leq F^{-1}(u), Y \leq G^{-1}(v))\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbb{P}(X \leq F^{-1}(u), X > -G^{-1}(v)) + \mathbb{P}(X \leq F^{-1}(u), X \leq G^{-1}(v)) \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbb{P}(X \leq \min\{F^{-1}(u), G^{-1}(v)\}) + \mathbb{P}(X \in [-G^{-1}(u), F^{-1}(v)])  \right]  = \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[ v - F(G^{-1}(v)) + F(\min\{F^{-1}(u), G^{-1}(v)\})  \right]
\end{array} \tag{1}$$

It seems I might be able to untangle this as a function of $(u,v)$ if I find $F(G^{-1}(v))$. However, here I'm not too sure that the usual approach of finding the inverse works.

$$ y = G(G^{-1}(y)) =\frac{1}{2}[1 + F(G^{-1}(y)) - F(-G^{-1}(y))] $$
$$ 2y -1  = F(G^{-1}(y)) - F(-G^{-1}(y)) $$
$$ F^{-1}(2y -1)  = F^{-1}\left(  F(G^{-1}(y)) -F(-G^{-1}(y)) \right) \tag{2}$$

But CDF's aren't necessarily subadditive, are they?

**My question:** the goal is to simplify $(1)$ to some convenient form, my idea is that finding the expression for $G^{-1}(y)$ would help, but I got stuck at $(2)$.

Is there another way to solve this? Or am I just missing something? Can we further work with $(2)$ to extract the $G^{-1}(y)$ expression?

Comment: What are you really looking for? Do you want to find $F(G^{-1}(v))$? It is not clear what are you asking.

Comment: @the_candyman  Thanks, I will edit my question. In short, I'm hoping to simplify the $C(u,v)$ expression. I.e., just as $F(F^{-1}(v)) = v$, I'm hoping that $F(G^{-1}(u)) =$ to something convenient. I know $G(y)$, but deriving $G^{-1}(y)$ does not seem trivial. Unless there's some rule that $F(x) - F(y) = F(x,y)$, from which I could extract $G^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: Since there's a chance I might be wrong in some of the middle steps, In order to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I tried to expand a bit on where my question is coming from, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.